# Firebase Cloud Messaging: send push notification after the app was reinstalled

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to send targeted (to a concrete device or device group) push notification with some special offers after my app was reinstalled? FCM registration token changes when user reinstalls the app, so `UIDevice.identifierForVendor` does.

The only option I see is to use Firebase authentication which will generate UIDs for users which are the same as long as user uses the same account (even after the app is reinstalled). The idea is to associate Firebase UID with FCM registration token for the users we want to send some special offers. When our app was reinstalled then we request Firebase UID + FCM registration token again. The token will be renewed one while UID should stay the same. It will allow us to continue sending push notifications to those who should get the special offer.

Is this workaround necessary or is there an option to continue sending push notifications after my app was reinstalled without any authentication?

Comment: i am not sure about authentication, meanwhile you can store your own unique id on device keychain, even after reinstall you can find/read id from keychain storage, this can be other workaround